# Session error when adding translation feature in Symfony2 application

Tags: php, session, symfony, translation

I have an error when I add translation feature in my Symfony application : here is the error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyApp\FilmothequeBundle\Controller\DefaultController::get() in C:\wamp\www\Symfony2\src\MyApp\FilmothequeBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php on line 41

the line 41 is :

```
$this->container->get('session')->setLocale($langue);
```

and it is in this controller function :

```
public function choisirLangueAction($langue = null)
{
    if($langue != null)
    {
        // On enregistre la langue en session
        $this->container->get('session')->setLocale($langue);
    }
    // on tente de rediriger vers la page d'origine
    $url = $this->container->get('request')->headers->get('referer');
    if(empty($url)) {
        $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('myapp_accueil');
    }
    return new RedirectResponse($url);
}
```

and I have the error when I press this link :

```
<a href="{{ path('myapp_choisir_langue', {'langue' : 'fr'}) }}">FR</a>
```

and here is the part of routing file that match :

```
myapp_choisir_langue:
   pattern: /choisir-langue/{langue}
   defaults: { _controller: MyAppFilmothequeBundle:Default:choisirLangue, _locale: fr}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `->get('service_name')` directly from your controller as in [symfony2 doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/controller.html#accessing-other-services).

Comment: You should not add a signature to your answer.